# Override swagger discerption/example using @ApiModelProperty in the inherited class fields

Tags: java, inheritance, swagger, swagger-ui

I have two classes

```
public class Account {
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "EUR")
    private CurrencyCode currency;
    ....// public setters and getters
}
```

and

```
public class SpecificAccount extends Account {
    //Here I need to override the currencie example without redefining the currency field
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "USD")  
    private CurrencyCode currency;
}
```

Can we override swagger discerption/example using @ApiModelProperty in inherited class ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add @ApiModel annotations, also classes should have getters for all fields you want to have documented.

If you have only getters, then args constructor is required, in case you have getters and setters then default one is enough.

```
@ApiModel(subTypes = {SpecificAccount.class})
public class Account {...}

@ApiModel(parent = Account.class)
public class SpecificAccount extends Account {...}
```